# Por que la regla de request.auth != null no funciona en Firestore V9?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, backend, firestore

Tengo mi app en firestore y estoy buscando limitar el acceso a traves de las reglas, pero la cuestion es que por alguna razon una regla basica como la siguiente no funciona, alguien sabe el motivo?

````
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null
    }
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

El if que colocaste no devuelve nada, es por eso que no funciona. Para este caso puedes utilizar el operador OR (||).

```
 allow read: request.auth || false
```

Básicamente lo que hace ahí es, si el request.auth es truthy (es truthy mientras no tenga valor como false, 0, '', null, ...) toma el valor del resquest.auth, si en caso es falsy, toma el valor del false.

Más detalle de los operadores [aquí](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/operator-lookup/)